Guarantying optimality on use of ADAM optimizer
Is it guaranteed to reach the global optimum by using the ADAM method?

Hello and welcome to Signal Processing SE. I believe your question is somewhat broad and could benefit from some more information. Furthermore, it is considered good practice to at least clarify your acronyms as not all everyone is necessarily familiar with all acronyms.

ADAM Optimizer is a 1st order optimizer.
As such, for a smooth function, all it can guarantee is convergence into a stationary point.
It means something globally only in the case of a Convex Function.
Though the ADAM optimizer, in the context of Deep Learning has many empirical good properties, it doesn't guarantee such things in the general case.

Thank you for your answer.

@alinouruzi, If it answers your question, could you mark it with the V sign on the left?
